# How to get AWS static file urls from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the urls to a few static images from my AWS S3 bucket. I have a couple of javascript functions that change the image a user clicks on (clicking on a like button turns it green). I'm having trouble getting those images to work. The farthest I've gotten was getting a 403 error (Forbidden), and I'm not entirely sure why. Right now, I'm defining a few url variables in script tag and calling them in my JS function.

Defining variables:

```
<script>
  var is_bookmark_url = "{% static 'img/is-bookmark.svg' %}";
  var bookmark_url = "{% static 'img/bookmark.svg' %}";
  var like_button = "{% static 'img/like-button.svg' %}";
  var liked_button = "{% static 'img/like-button-liked.svg' %}";
</script>
```

Calling Variables in JS Function:

```
function changeLike(id) {
    el = document.querySelector('#' + id)
    source = el.src
    if (source.substring(source.length - 26) == "/img/like-button-liked.svg" || 
        source.substring(33, 59) == "/img/like-button-liked.svg") {
        el.src = like_button_url;
    } else { 
        el.src = liked_button_url;
    }
}
```

(I know my function is the opposite of elegant, but I wasn't sure how else to get the image names from the urls -- but it works at least.)

The point where I'm having trouble is I'm getting the error

```
GET https://appname.s3.amazonaws.com/img/bookmark.svg?
AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXX%3D&amp;Expires=1586147111 
403 (Forbidden)
```

So it's definitely generating a url, but it's forbidden. Why is that?

Comment: I think you don't have access to those images, you need to make those images public in S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clearly showing that the app doesn't have access to the `S3` object.

You need to make the `S3` object public to access it.

**To make an individual object public, follow these steps:**

1. From the Amazon S3 console, choose the bucket with the object that
   you want to update.
2. Navigate to the folder that contains the object.
3. Open the object by choosing the link on the object name.
4. Choose the Permissions tab.
5. Under Public access, choose Everyone.